# Go to back directory browsing after opening file in vim

Tags: vim

When I open a directory browsing in vim, I can open a file by moving the cursor to a file name and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Now, is there any command to go back to the previous directory browsing?

If not, is there a way to open a file without closing the directory browsing mode?

Comment: I am not sure, but if you want really convenient directory browsing, I recommend that you check out NERDTree

Answer (score 301, accepted):

You can go back to the last buffer using `:b#`.

If you just opened a file, then it will bring you just back to the directory browsing.

**Update**:
Since this answer happened to be accept as the correct answer and is thus on the top, I'd like to summarize a bit the answers, including the one by @romainl that imho is the correct one.

- `:Rex[plore]`: Return to Explorer ([by @romainl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14030101/1141095)) [vimdoc.sourceforge](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pi_netrw.html#:Rexplore)
- `:Explorer`: opens the Explorer, same as `:E` (if no other command starting with `E` is defined (see [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14367507/1141095)), or as `:Ex` (see [vim.wikia](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/File_explorer)) ([by @drug_user841417](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12320927/1141095)).
- `:b#`: goes back to the "previously edited buffers". See [vim.wikia](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Easier_buffer_switching#Switching_to_the_previously_edited_buffer)
- `:e#` or `Ctrl`-`6` (or `Ctrl`-`^`): goes back to the "previously edited file" ([by @aman-jain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16070880/1141095)). See [vim.wikia](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#CTRL-%5E)
- `Ctrl`-`O`: jump back to the previous (older) location, not necessarily a buffer ([by @Peyman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9183377/1141095)). See [vim.wikia](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Jumping_to_previously_visited_locations)

Comment: That should be `:b#`. I'd fix it, but single-character edits don't fly.

Comment: If I do `vim <dirname>` and then navigate to the file and press `Enter`, it does not work; if i open vim, then `:e <dirname>`, select file and `Enter`, it works. In both cases `:buffers` shows only one buffer. I'm not sure why it is so.

Comment: @mcmlxxxvi according to the vim wiki `b#` only works for "previously edited buffers": http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Easier_buffer_switching?action=edit&section=6

Comment: How about on a mac?

Comment: @DanielGelling sorry for the late answer. But yes, should be the same on Mac

Comment: Nice thing summarizing all the other correct answers, I wish more people do that.

Comment: @ezdazuzena please add `Ctrl`-`i` for jumping forward so it can be used really nice with `Ctrl`-`o` for switching between the files

Comment: @veich Thanks for your comment, but I won't do that for now since the question is only about going backward. This is not a wiki page, I'm just summarizing the other questions for the sake of clarity. Hope you understand that.

Comment: How does :Explore differ to :Explorer?

Comment: There is no built-in :Explorer. What are you referring to @ThomasStokes

Answer (score 104):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> to go back to the previous buffer.

Comment: Very useful in general (e.g. for navigating back from `gf`), but in case of exploring directories it doesn't bring me back to the "line" I was on when opening the file. `:Rex<Enter>`, which is somewhat clumsy (5 keystrokes vs 1), does it. Probably this is a candidate for mapping...

Answer (score 52):

The proper command for returning to the netrw listing is `:Rex[plore]`. You can run it even after you have jumped to and from dozens of files.

Comment: When editing a file after leaving the netrw listing, is returning with `:Rexplore` any different from returning with `:Explore`?

Comment: To answer my own question, it appears that `:Rexplore` always returns you to the same netrw listing that you were browsing before, whereas `:Explore` gives the listing for the directory of whatever file is open currently.

Answer (score 40):

`:Ex` will take you back (and show you what you edited and didn't save).

Comment: I upvoted EVERY one of the answers. they were all useful

Comment: Nice, it is a bit better than `Ctrl-O` because it highlights the parent directory (`..`), instead of the top line (some Netrw header), but it's still not where I left the explorer (the opened file). 4 keystrokes vs 1, some saving of `j`s to navigate down to where I was, but still I am likely to map `:Rex<Enter>` if I'm expecting a lot of navigation.

Answer (score 32):

I rely on Ctrl ^ to go back and forth b/w two buffers.

Comment: This worked for me with vim 7.3 on OSX from homebrew. Ctrl-O does not seem to work.

Comment: You don't even need shift, can just Ctrl 6

Comment: more correctly, this "edits the alternate file": http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#CTRL-^

Comment: Excellent! Albeit it just works back and forth (like a "1 level Undo"), but it actually returns to the line I was on! Looks like I'm not mapping `:Rex<CR>` after all! (Of course, only when I don't look forward to "go back" from nested navigations (jumped to another file etc.).

Comment: On a MacBook, it is CTRL + SHIFT + 6, not just Ctrl + 6

Answer (score 27):

I usually just use `:E`. It's easy to remember and gets you back to the directory listing of the file you had open.

Comment: I'm surprised this has too few votes. It's definitely an answer.

Comment: Don't be surprised - on my current vim 7.4.x `:E` is ambiguous and does nothing. You need to type a least `:E<CR>`.

Comment: This is the same as `:Ex` or `:Explorer` if not other command starting with `E` is defined. See for instance https://stackoverflow.com/a/14367507/1141095

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to use the **Jump-motions** shortcut keys to do any 'go back' or 'go forward' actions in Vim. It makes vim like a web browser.

You can search for Vim's help for more details.

> Vim `:h jump-motions`

So like as mentioned in other answers **ctrl+O** works cool, and hope vim's help-file let you learn more commands like **ctrl+I** .

<kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd>  +  <kbd>**I**</kbd>  : Go Forward

<kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd> +  <kbd>**O**</kbd>  : Go Back