# Map :E to :Explore in command mode?

Tags: vim

How can I map `:E` to `:Explore`?  I've installed an extension that leads to `E464: Ambiguous use of user-defined command` if I do `:E` now, but my fingers won't forget the command!

I tried `map :E :Explore`, but that's ugly since it makes accessing the other commands difficult.

I tried these:

```
cmap :E<CR> :Explore<CR>
cmap :E^M :Explore^M
```

(where `^M` = control-v + enter) but these don't work unless I hit enter really really fast.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`:E` would normally suffice as is if `:Explore` were the only defined command that began with an `E`. You evidently have multiple such commands defined, so `:E` is ambiguous and results in an error.

`:cmap` causes immediate literal substitution and thus has unwanted side effects. A slightly better alternative is `:cabbrev`, which can be used to define abbreviations for command mode:

```
cabbrev E Explore
```

This triggers following <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>. The former is desired because typing <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>E</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> will invoke `:Explore`, but the latter again has side effects in command mode.

In order for `:E` to be properly aliased to `:Explore`, it must be defined as a separate command:

```
command! E Explore
```

However, `:command E`, which lists all defined commands that start with `E`, reveals that `:E` and `:Explore` have different properties. For example, it's impossible to execute `:E ~` because `:E` does not accept any arguments. Also, unlike `:Explore`, `:E` does not autocomplete directories.

To remedy these deficiencies, `:E` must be defined in exactly the same way as `:Explore`. Executing `:verbose command Explore` shows the location of the script in which `:Explore` is defined; `:E` can then be defined in the same manner, with the addition of `<args>`:

```
command! -nargs=* -bar -bang -count=0 -complete=dir E Explore <args>
```

While it's possible to deduce most of these attributes from the information provided by `:command Explore`, there can still be discrepancies, such as `-bar` in this case.

N.B. If `:Explore` and `:Example` are defined, `:Exp` and `:Exa` are the shortest unambiguous commands that can be used. Explicitly aliasing `:E` to one of them, as above, overrides Vim's default behavior and allows for disambiguation. However, `:Ex` would still be ambiguous.

Comment: Another quick way to open up the explorer is using `:e.`. This will `:Explore` the current directory. This also has the nice benefit of not needing the shift key.

Comment: @PeterRincker Neat, but for a totally different use case.

Comment: For the complete n00b, put `command! E Explore` in your `~/.vimrc` file, then :E will properly alias to :Explore.