# Netrw open in active directory

Tags: vim, netrw

I want `Netrw` (`:e`) to open in same folder of the file I'm currently looking at. For example,

```
A
...B
   ...file1.txt
   ...file2.txt
```

If I run `:e` inside of folder `A`, navigate into folder `B`, open up `file1.txt`, and then run `:e` again, I would like Netrw to open up with `B` as the directory, and not `A`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer in [this](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/the-file-explorer/) Vimcast. `:Explore` or `:E` will open up Netrw in the current file's directory. I got an `ambiguous use of user-defined command` error at first when I tried to use `:E`, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14367440/map-e-to-explore-in-command-mode) SO answer helped fix that. I just had to add this command to my `.vimrc`, `command! -nargs=* -bar -bang -count=0 -complete=dir E Explore <args>`. `:E` only works if there are no other possible commands that start with `:E`.

Comment: It's best to post the actual solution with an attribution rather than just a link to the solution.  Who knows how long vimcasts will be around.

Answer (score 0):

Try `set autochdir` in your .vimrc